# Probability questions involving complements

Tags: probability

Among 35 students in a class, 17 earned “A” on the midterm, 14 earned “A” on the final exam, and 11 did not earn “A” on either exam. What is the probability that a randomly selected student from this class earned “A” on both exams?

So in my solution I did:

Let A = students who earned “A” on the midterm 
Let B = students who earned “A” on final

So the formula that I follow is: 
P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B)

My only question is, why is P(A ∪ B) a complement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$P(A\cup B)$ is not a complement, it is a probability.

$A\cup B$ is the complement of $(A\cup B)^c=A^c\cap B^c$, by (de Morgan and) the very definition of complement. ($C^c$ denotes the complement of $C$ with respect to a base set $\Omega$ here, i.e. $C^c=\Omega\setminus C$. Omega denotes the set of all students of the class in your case.)

In your context, $A\cup B$ is the set of all students who received an "A" on at least 1 of the 2 exams. $A^c$ is the set of students who didn't received an "A" on midterms, $B^c$ is the set of students who didn't received an "A" on endterms, so $A^c\cap B^c=(A\cup B)^c$ is the set of students who didn't received an "A" on either exam.

That way, you would calculate the probability of people who passed by

$$P(A\cup B) = 1-P((A\cup B)^c) = 1-P(A^c\cap B^c)$$

---

Since you select randomly, which means uniformly distributed in this case, so you are conducting a Laplace experiment and thus, for any $C\subseteq \Omega$

$$P(C)=\frac{|C|}{|\Omega|}$$

where $|\cdot|$ denotes the number of elements in the set and $\Omega$ is teh base set (so $|\Omega|=35$ in your case).

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, see the Venn diagram:

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]
$$\begin{cases}a+c=17\\ b+c=14 \\ a+b+c+11=35\end{cases} \overbrace{\Rightarrow}^{(1)+(2)-(3)} c=11-4=7 \Rightarrow \\
\color{blue}{P(A\cap B)}=\frac{c}{35}=\color{blue}{\frac{7}{35}}.$$
Now expressed in terms of probabilities:
$$\begin{align}\color{red}{P(A)}=&\frac{n(A)}{n(S)}=\frac{a+c}{35}=\frac{17}{35}; \\
\color{red}{P(B)}=&\frac{n(B)}{n(S)}=\frac{b+c}{35}=\frac{14}{35};\\
P((A\cup B)^C)=&\frac{n((A\cup B)^C)}{n(S)}=\frac{35-(a+b+c)}{35}=\\
=&1-\frac{a+b+c}{35}=1-P(A\cup B)=\frac{11}{35} \Rightarrow \\
\color{red}{P(A\cup B)}=&1-\frac{11}{35}=\frac{24}{35};\\
\color{blue}{P(A\cap B)}=&\frac{n(A\cap B)}{n(S)}=\frac{c}{35}=\frac{n(A)+n(B)-n(A\cup B)}{n(S)}=\\
=&\frac{n(A)}{n(S)}+\frac{n(B)}{n(S)}-\frac{n(A\cup B)}{n(S)}=\\
=&\color{red}{P(A)}+\color{red}{P(B)}-\color{red}{P(A\cup B)}=\\
=&\frac{17}{35}+\frac{14}{35}-\frac{24}{35}=\color{blue}{\frac{7}{35}}.\end{align}$$

Note the complements: $P((A\cup B)^C)=1-P(A\cup B)$.